# OpenSubKey() Registry key's “Absolute Path”?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry, registrykey

Using `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` C# functions which require a registry path, like `OpenSubKey()`, using a path like

```
@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp"
```

generates an error stating **“Absolute path information is required.”**

What is the syntax to create the absolute path required?

Comment: From where are you obtaining a `RegistryKey`?  Showing the exact, relevant code you're using would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registry has a couple of root keys and all subkeys are relative to one of these.

> In order to use the OpenSubKey method, you must have an instance of the RegistryKey method. To get an instance of RegistryKey, use one of the static members of the Registry class.

If for example you want the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet` as seen in Regedit you would have to start with `Registry.LocalMachine`.

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet");
... = rk.GetValue(...);
```

If you already have a key, `yourkey.Name` is the path of the key.